# Nginx always return Empty reply from server during creating cache file

Tags: nginx, caching

Nginx i am trying to use fast_cgi_cache, but it always returns empty reply from server during make some cache files.

If there aren't cache file then return always empty reply from server, and after a few seconds, then make some cache file(in tmp directory) and works corretly.

There are ways to remove empty reply with cache?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this prbolem.
just added `use_temp_path=off` to nginx fastcgi cache path.

```
NGINX first writes files that are destined for the cache to a temporary storage 
area, and the use_temp_path=off directive instructs NGINX to write them to the 
same directories where they will be cached. We recommend that you set this 
parameter to off to avoid unnecessary copying of data between file systems. 
use_temp_path was introduced in NGINX version 1.7.10 and NGINX Plus R6.
```

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/